# Error using pdfx on Tex Live 2021

Tags: texlive, pdfx, xmp

After switching from Tex Live 2019 to 2021, `pdfx` doesn't seem to work correctly.
MWE that works on 2019 but not on 2021:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{Some document}
    \Author{Some author}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
This document won't compile on \TeX{} Live 2021.
\end{document}
```

Tex Live 2021's pdflatex shows multiple repetitions of the following errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2855  \includexmp{\xmp@template}
                                  %
?
```

In addition, some XMP tree is included as document text (in contrast to metadata as would have been expected).

To me, it seems that Tex Live 2021 has a regression (lualatex and xelatex seem to fail in a similar way). Tex Live 2021 was installed today and thus is fully up to date. Maybe I'm missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605650/why-does-latex-complain-im-missing-begindocument#comment1518627_605650

Comment: your document runs without error with `pdflatex-dev` rather than`pdflatex`

Comment: Thanks! The other question unfortunately didn't show up during my search - guess my search terms were too specific...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it works in -dev only because -dev hasn't yet the fix for https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/605, as soon as this is there too, it will break too. So this really need to be fixed in pdfx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes but if the OP wants to get a document out today....

Comment: Possible alternative: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612219/128553

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

With xmpincl 2021/08/31 v2.3 this patch is no longer needed

---

You can try this patch

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
    \Title{Some document}
    \Author{Some author}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2021-06-01}%
 {\AddToHook{package/after/xmpincl}
   {\patchcmd\mcs@xmpincl@patchFile{\if\par}{\ifx\par}{}{\fail}}}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
This document won't compile on \TeX{} Live 2021.
\end{document}
```

Comment: works for me.. could you elaborate on what does it do?

Comment: it replaces a wrong `\if` in xmpincl by the correct `\ifx`.

Comment: If this patch does not break anything, could that fix be incorporated directly into the xmpincl package in CTAN? That package has currently no active maintainer, so anyone can submit a bugfix.

Comment: @JarmoNiemelä. Sure. Contact ctan and tell them you are willing to do it. I won't do it. I don't neither use xmpincl nor pdfx (pdfx is incompatible with pdfmanagement-testphase).

Comment: I added this fix to xmpincl and submitted a corrected version to CTAN.

Comment: This patch can cause pdf/a validation errors. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Since I don't know how to fix `pdfx`, I built a temporary workaround package `fixpdfx.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{fixpdfx}[2021-07-22 A package that fixes pdfx errors on TeX Live 2021 in a quick and dirty way]

% temporarily reverts https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/5fb2860f2fedc87b213730f06ec1d77bcab4814a
% resp. https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/dd2ec509ec98e9c359a41e35aea6aade86485ca2
% as it breaks pdfx (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605854/error-using-pdfx-on-tex-live-2021)
% published on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605854/error-using-pdfx-on-tex-live-2021/610445#610445 

\@ifpackageloaded{pdfx}{
    \PackageError{fixpdfx}{pdfx is loaded}{This package must be loaded before pdfx}
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% this is the old implementation from base/ltpara.dtx, version 1.0g
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__old_para_end: {
  % ltpara v1.0h as well as firstaid/latex2e-first-aid-for-external-files.dtx v1.0o inserted
  % \scan_stop: here, which breaks pdfx
  \mode_if_horizontal:TF {
    \mode_if_inner:F {
         \tex_unskip:D
         \hook_use:n{para/end}
         \@kernel@after@para@end
         \mode_if_horizontal:TF {
           \if_int_compare:w 0 < \tex_lastnodetype:D
             \tex_kern:D \c_zero_dim
           \fi:
           \tex_par:D
           \hook_use:n{para/after}
           \@kernel@after@para@after
         }
         { \msg_error:nnnn { hooks }{ para-mode }{end}{horizontal} }
    }
  }
  \tex_par:D
}

\PackageWarning{fixpdfx}{Patching~\para_end:~implementation~to~fix~pdfx}
\cs_set_eq:NN \par     \__old_para_end:
% these two aren't actually required to fix pdfx, so we'll skip them...
%\cs_set_eq:NN \@@par   \__old_para_end:
%\cs_set_eq:NN \endgraf \__old_para_end:

\AtBeginDocument{
    \@ifpackageloaded{pdfx}{}{
        \PackageError{fixpdfx}{pdfx~is~not~loaded}{You~did~not~load~pdfx~and~thus~do~not~need~this~package}
    }
    % pdfx v1.6.3 from 2019-02-27 is bad, so anything later is hopefully fixed...
    \@ifpackagelater{pdfx}{2019/02/28}{
        \PackageError{fixpdfx}{Please~check~whether~you~really~need~this~package.}{Your~pdfx~package~is~more~recent~than~2019-02-27~and~thus~might~not~require~this~package's~fix.}
    }{}

    \PackageWarning{fixpdf}{Restoring~old~\para_end:~implementation}
    
    % restore additional definitions
    \cs_set_eq:NN \par     \para_end:
    % see above: as we didn't replace them, no need to restore them.
    %\cs_set_eq:NN \@@par   \para_end:
    %\cs_set_eq:NN \endgraf \para_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

`fixpdfx` has to be loaded *before* `pdfx` and reverts the [fix for issue 605](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/605). At the start of the document, however, `pdfx` has already included the XMP metadata in the output document and everything gets reverted.
This way, other packages should hopefully not break (especially since `pdfx` loads `hyperref` and thus should be loaded very late anyway).

At least that's the fix I'll be using until `pdfx` is hopefully fixed some day... (or someone proposes a better fix)

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike Fischer suggested in her answer above, the error in question originated from the xmpincl package called by pdfx. The culprit was the following line in xmpincl.sty version 2.2:

```
\if\par\xmpinclReadln\else%
```

In version 2.3 this line is replaced with

```
\ifx\par\xmpinclReadln\else%
```

This removes the error, but as it turned out, it doesn't work as intended. The purpose of this line is to filter out empty lines from the input `.xmp` file because otherwise they would be output as `\par` commands. Unfortunately, the condition `\ifx\par\xmpinclReadln` is never true, and that will cause some `\par` commands to pass through to the generated pdf file. This, in turn, will cause PDF/A validation errors.

I should have tested it more thoroughly before I uploaded version 2.3 to CTAN; sorry about that. To correct my mistake, I have now submitted a new version 2.4 of xmpincl where the above-mentioned line is replaced with

```
\if\endline\xmpinclReadln\else%
```

In my tests, this seemed to work without problems.

And as David Carlisle pointed out in his comment, the error in question does not happen at all with `pdflatex-dev`. So this might be only a temporary problem and will go away after the next release of LaTeX.

Comment: no, the next release will not resolve it. It worked temporarly in pdflatex-dev as pdflatex-dev was *behind* the latex release for some days. But this has changed.

Comment: I just tested that pdflatex-dev (LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-9-23 branch)) still works with xmpincl version 2.2.

Comment: Version 2.2 of xmpincl.sty does _not_ work anymore with pdflatex-dev (LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> pre-release-2 (develop 2021-10-4 branch)).