# How to generate a PDF/A-3b document with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: pdf

I want to convert my document to PDF/A-3b. I'm using lualatex and I have a custom font if that matters. I've tried setting the pdf attributes with hyperref, but that appears to not be enough. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 7):

(updated 2023-10 to the new state of the project)

You can try with the new pdfmanagement of LaTeX. It creates xmp-metadata. hyperxmp is not compatible anymore and should not be used.

```
\DocumentMetadata{pdfstandard=A-3b}
   
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle=test,pdfauthor=me}

\begin{document}
some text

\end{document}
```

Be aware that "testphase" means that this in the testphase and not every package is already compatible. Check the documentation if needed.

Answer (score 2):

`LaTeX`can't produce PDF/A out of the box. You either need to use the `pdfx` or the `hyperxmp` package. `pdfx` is meant as the all-in-one solutions for all kind of PDF varieties, but it's rather fragile, so `hyperxmp` might be the better solution.

Check out [PDF/A with hyperref on TeX Live 2013](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130201/pdf-a-with-hyperref-on-tex-live-2013/136653#136653) and [PDF/A with CMYK, how?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227429/pdf-a-with-cmyk-how/536060#536060) for some hints how to go about this.