# Error with pdfx package compiled with lualatex

Tags: luatex, compilation-error, pdfx

I need to compile my thesis as a PDF/A-compliant document. Therefore I use the **pdfx package**.
Reacently (due to many many tikz figures) I have changed from pdflatex to **lualatex** (TeX memory - externalization is not an option, because I have links of acronyms and citations in my figures).
Lualatex compiles a full pdf but raises the error:

> (c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty
> Package: pdfx 2019/02/27 v1.6.3 PDF/X and PDF/A support (CVR/HTH/RRM/PS)
> \pdfx@minorversion=\count440
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.   \scan_stop:
> l.332
> A number should have been here; I inserted '0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up `weird error' in the
> index to The TeXbook.)

The latest version of TeX live have not fixed this issue. Is this a bug or a input error, which I could solve? I am happy for any help. Thanks!

My MWE looks like that:

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
11pt,
BCOR=10mm,  DIV=14, headinclude, headheight=16mm, twoside, openright, onecolumn,
parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.5,0.0}
\definecolor{myOrange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0.055}
\definecolor{myBlue}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,0.7}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet,mathpazo}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% ###--- Own Page Style ---###
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{} %to set pagenumber in footer on first pages of chapters
% ###--- Page Style END ---###

\usepackage{scrhack} %to delete warning <\float@addtolists detected!>

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{float} %[H]
\usepackage{enumitem} %This package provides user control over the layout of the three basic list environments: enumerate, itemize and description.
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    breaklinks=true,
    colorlinks=true, 
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=darkblue,
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    linktoc=all,
    pdfstartview=Fit,       %fit to full page
    pdfpagelayout=TwoPageLeft %display pdf in two page view (book)
]{hyperref}

%TODO: check if with texlive 2022 solved?
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx} %error with lualatex!!! 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 

\tolerance=300
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%
%%
%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Title page
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter
Intro
\tableofcontents
%%%%%%%%%%%
\mainmatter
Main text.
%%%%%%%%%
\appendix
Appendix
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex,don't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` either (although that does no harm ,just gives a warning that it should not be used)

Comment: Seems like the package pdfx being incompatible with lualatex. One option is to nicely ask the pdfx developer to fix it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605854/error-using-pdfx-on-tex-live-2021/606007#606007

Comment: load `\usepackage{luatex85}` before pdfx. @DavidCarlisle the other bug is imho resolved.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just came back here to say the same:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so slow ;-)

Comment: This should be reported as a bug to the pdfx developrs though, no package should be requiring luatex85 by now, that was a short term patch to help documents with the name changes in the luatex 0.85 beta release.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Me surprised you don't suggest to use pdfmanagement-testphase with simply `\DocumentMetadata{pdfstandard=A-1b}`. OK, tried myself and besides no error, no success, because verapdf says »The document catalog dictionary of a conforming file shall contain the Metadata key.« and »If a document information dictionary does appear at a document, then all of its entries that have analogous properties in predefined XMP schemas, shall also be embedded in the file in XMP form with equivalent values.« I commented out pdfx, of course.

Comment: @KeksDose you need hyperxmp too to get the xmp data.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and comprehensive replies. The workaround suggested by @DavidCarlisle works as discribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround suggested by @DavidCarlisle works as discribed.

Adding the line `\usepackage{luatex85}` **before** `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}` removed the compilation error with lualatex.